# PIG: Read a bag and emit individual tuples

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have the following bag of data:

*({(key1,value1),(key1,value2)})
({(key2,value1),(key2,value1)})*

The above data is stored in a file/relation & it has two rows of data where each row is a bag.

Is there a way of reading each bag emitting every tuple out of the bag?

*Ex: Here I would like to emit
(key1,value1)
(key1,value2)
(key2,value1)
(key2,value2)*

Please help.
PIG is driving me crazy :( :(

Comment: Have you tried FLATTEN()? http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/basic.html#flatten

Comment: can you provide (a sample of) the content of your file and your current Pig query?

Comment: Thanks @LiMuBei. FLATTEN() helped.
Add that as an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FLATTEN() should do the trick :) http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/basic.html#flatten